# Why is Dimensions slowing down App Performance (react-native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to find out, whether the Device is in Portrait or Landscape. Doing that, I use the `onLayout()` Method which every `<View/>` provides. When `onLayout()` is triggered, I use the `Dimensions()` to get the `width` and `height` which tells me, how the device is hold. 
I am not implementing it on the very top `<View/>` of my App, but on a certain screen. The screen I am implementing it on is filled completely with the `<View/>` I am using the function `onLayout()` and `Dimensions()`  on.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Dimensions,
} from "react-native";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent.js"


export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state({
            portrait: null,
            data: [...]
        })
    }

    _orientation = (event) => {
        const size = Dimensions.get("window");
        size.height > size.width ? this.setState({ landscape: false }) : this.setState({ landscape: true })
    }

    _createChildComponent = () => {
        const portrait = this.state.portrait;
        const childComponentList = this.state.data.map((obj, index) => {
            return <ChildComponent
                key={index}
                data={obj}
                portrait={portrait}/>
        });
        return childComponentList;
    }

    render() {
        const createdChildComponent = this._createChildComponent();
            return (
                <View 
                    onLayout={(event) => {this._orientation(event)}}>
                        {createdChildComponent}
                </View>
            )
        }
}
```

In the `ChildComponent` I access the relevant `props` via

```
...this.props.portrait...
```

Implementing it, slows down my App terribly. It even crashes sometimes. I have no clue why. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you check how many times it is called? It might get called too much

Comment: @Salketer when I log the `event` in `_orientation()` it only gets logged once.